# Click event listener on a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have this event that listens for a click on a img then it switches the img for another, but this img can get real small and I wanted to make the entire tr click able. Any suggestions?

```
$('#example tbody td img').live('click', function () {
                var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
                {
                    /* This row is already open - close it */
                    this.src = "images/details_open.png";
                    oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Open this row */
                    this.src = "images/details_close.png";
                    oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
                }
            } );
```

**Update**
I tried using this but now my img won't change. How would I select the img to use (this) or do I just make a var for it?

```
$('#example tbody td').on('click', function (e) {
        var myImage = $(this).find("img");
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        myImage.src = "images/details_open.png";
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
        /* Open this row */
        myImage.src = "images/details_close.png";
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: kindly check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: it's now better to use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which is now deprecated by the way.

second: just add a handler for the td, and by nature, it will get the same click event that will occur on your img, then you can eaisly select the img and play with it like nomral, consider the following example which is using the better way of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Update:** I've modified the code a little bit to make it better

```
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
        var myImage = $(this).find("img");
        var nTr = this.closest('tr');
                if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
                {
                    /* This row is already open - close it */
                    myImage.src = "images/details_open.png";
                    oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Open this row */
                    myImage.src = "images/details_close.png";
                    oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
                }
}
```

you should now be ok with this solution, let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pretty Simple

Select td instead of `img`

```
 $('#example tbody td').on('click', function () {
```

<sub>P.S: Of course the live function has been deprecated so its better to use `.on()`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Select the `td` and bind the click event to it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohammed ElSayed says .live() is deprecated..

But.. in my case, when i create on the fly elements

```
 .on('click', function(){})
```

doesn't work for me...

So try using .live() in the td

```
$('#example tbody td').live('click', function()...);
```

The same happends to me with (doesn't work)

```
$('#example').prop('name');
```

Just commenting maybe i'm doing something bad with that.

Comment: [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is working fine for current and future DOM elements, but it need a little different syntax than live(),  so instead of `.on('click', function(){})`, you will need to make it like this `.on('click','Selector_for_target_elements', function(){})`

Comment: great! i tried it and runs just as expected! so... just for get sure i understand it.. you atach te .on() to an elemen that isn't going to be created on-the-fly (for example an <ul>) and then you filter by the element you want to trigger (4ex.. <li>). thats right?

Comment: just to clarify more, you are narrowing the selector scope by defining the first element (so the selector will not start from the top of your document, and instead will start from the provided one) then you filter by the item that you need to handle the provided event with, whether the item is currently exist or expected to become available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the click event to TD tag, then find image inside the clicked target and change its source. Here:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
              var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
              var clickedImg = $(e.target).find('img')[0]; 

            if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
            {
                /* This row is already open - close it */
                clickedImg.src = "images/details_open.png";
                oTable.fnClose( nTr );
            }
            else
            {
                /* Open this row */
                clickedImg.src = "images/details_close.png";
                oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
            }
        } );
```

I did not tried this, but it should work.